# Iterative string construction in Python while avoiding for loop

Tags: python, iterator, string-concatenation

I would like to create a set of identities using all combinations of three uppercase letters while avoiding `for` loops to save computation time. I would like to have identities that range from `ID_AAA` to `ID_ZZZ`.

I can do this using `for` loops:

```
> from string import ascii_uppercase 
> IDs = [] 
>  for id_first_letter in ascii_uppercase:   
>    for id_second_letter in ascii_uppercase:
>      for id_third_letter in ascii_uppercase:
>        IDs.append('ID_' + id_first_letter + id_second_letter + id_third_letter)
```

But of course I would like to simplify the code here. I have tried to use the `map` function but the best I could come up with was this:

```
> from string import ascii_uppercase
> IDs = list(map(lambda x,y,z: 'ID_' + x + y + z,ascii_uppercase,ascii_uppercase,ascii_uppercase))
```

This is iterating among all letters at the same time, so I can only get `ID_AAA`, `ID_BBB`, ..., `ID_ZZZ`. All three letters are always the same as a consequence. Can I fine-tune this approach in order to iterate one letter at a time or do I need to use a totally different approach?

Comment: You say you want to simplify your code, but your code already ***is*** really simple. Maybe the simplest. Why do you think avoiding loops will make it simpler?

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you! Yet I was really convinced that the use of the for loops was the least computationally efficient way to do this and I was convinced I could do this using the map function or in some other way that could run faster. It turns out that I cannot avoid the loops in any case, even with the itertools module.

Comment: Your code takes like 5 milliseconds. Is that too slow? For what?

Answer (score 2):

You are just reimplementing `itertools.product`.

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_uppercase 


IDs = [''.join(["ID_", *t]) for t in product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=3)]
```

or

```
IDs = [f'ID_{x}{y}{z}' for x, y, z in product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=3)]
```

depending on your preference for constructing a string from a trio produced by `product`.

Answer (score 1):

"Can I fine-tune this approach in order to iterate one letter at a time or do I need to use a totally different approach?"
Yes...it will be 3 independent loops. It doesn't matter if you use `map`, loops or comprehensions, it's syntactic sugar in this case, you have to go through all the possibilities in this case, no shortcuts imho.

You can use e.g. `product` from `itertools` to make it more readable though:

```py
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_uppercase 
IDs= []
for a,b,c in product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=3):
    IDs.append(f'ID_{a}{b}{c}')
```

Comment: `product`, not `permutations`.

Comment: `permutations` won't produce a string with duplicate characters like `AAA`.

Comment: You are right, `product`

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially doing this:

```
>>> [f'ID_{x}{y}{z}' for x in ascii_uppercase for y in ascii_uppercase for z in ascii_uppercase]
['ID_AAA', 'ID_AAB', 'ID_AAC', ... 'ID_ZZX', 'ID_ZZY', 'ID_ZZZ']
```

Which is otherwise known as a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

You can also just use [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [f'ID_{x}{y}{z}' for x,y,z in product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=3)]
['ID_AAA', 'ID_AAB', 'ID_AAC', ... 'ID_ZZX', 'ID_ZZY', 'ID_ZZZ']
```

And don't forget that it is *better* to refactor your code so that you don't generate the entire list if it is not necessary.

You can do this:

```
>>> ids_gen=(f'ID_{x}{y}{z}' for x in ascii_uppercase for y in ascii_uppercase for z in ascii_uppercase)
>>> next(ids_gen)
'ID_AAA' # and so on until exhausted...
```

or this:

```
>>> ids_gen=(f'ID_{x}{y}{z}' for x,y,z in product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=3))
>>> next(ids_gen)
'ID_AAA'
```

to generate one at a time.

(From comments, you can also do this generator:

```
from itertools import product, starmap
ids_gen=starmap("ID_{}{}{}".format, product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=3))
```

which is pretty cool...)

Comment: One more iterator: `starmap("ID_{}{}{}".format, product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=3))`

Comment: Question is closed, could you include one more? Looks fast. In function `Kelly` here:

Comment: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVRLTsMwFFywyyme2CShpmqLkFCl7tggjlBVVkjs1iixI-dFkFY9CRs2cCiuwQXwp4loGhDsLM94Zt57tl_eywY3Sr6-vtXIL28-zj65VgUIZBqVyisQRak0QqlVVqcYOLRCLeS6hZIqFYLWZcl0mlQMPAdFwQS2HM1KlmAQZIyD0mItZJJH8TwAuLutYAHLFZg1VxpERrnQFdKcoQkBQvYN5gCW3NErliqZ_cJ35I6OG6H_wHbJxonZllkU3t3SEEYn4Uan_qO-R2wENcNaS6voW3DP8rzx9XcdcB6rrjBqs-lErll0FR-FsmSRGSOv30HwvUx72toNgD-W7s37WdMNKyXT0zbuAV-G4fhRCRktz03wcwIXuIqdPlrpw32JehbkcBMWV_HqSH7Wl-e2H7vn_a7Z77b70Ck_E2gIbP-lnyVP65Psg-IDHXFA8xOwHexhwGuZ2iG195z4cZOuk91qRnw8c2Zo4naT202n6CtAI1yYrvsyI05A1sUD04vpJI4dozRv0wDhDuECppMJzK_HM76HooKQAB9TKpOCUWrZnhv7t3_4Atqv4As